# Access Airflow variable in Python DAG?

Tags: python, airflow

I know in SQL I can access things like `{{ ds }}`, can this be in done in regular Python code?

Like

```
dag = DAG(...)
my_date = '{{ ds }}'
```

Doesn't seem like it works, is it possible to get this value in raw Python code?

**Edit, main reason:**

Say we want to backfill, in that case in my SQL queries `{{ ds }}` will change to a prior date, but will `date.today()`  change for Python? Wondering about how to get parity in between SQL stuff and Python raw

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which Python code.

If you're using `PythonOperator` to run a Python function, those values can be passed to your callable:

```
def callable(ds, **kwargs):
    # ... use ds
    return
```

`date.today()` and similar values are *not* patched - the objective is not to simulate an environment in the past, but simply to pass parameters describing the time interval for the run.

For task definitions, certain operator parameters are templated. It's up to each operator which ones are templated. Operator documentation should indicate which arguments support templating.

For example, the [generated DatabricksSubmitRunOperator docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/_api/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks/index.html) indicate that `json` and all the fields that are inserted into keys of `json` will be templated.

Comment: I am actually using custom operators (Snowflake and Databricks). Is there a way to go about it for this

Comment: It doesn't look like SnowflakeOperator has anywhere to run Python code. Are you subclassing?

Comment: So what I am doing is.

Providing a SQL file to snowflake operator, and in the SQL its something like `COPY into mylocation/'{{ ds }}' SELECT * FROM table`, the `{{ ds }}` gets rendered in real time and it will work during backfills.

Fast forward to the actual DAG, my next operator is the Databricks Operator. In which I provide the `mylocation/'{{ ds }}'` as an input param, but I am currently using `mylocation/ + today.date()...`

So there is the inconsistency that SQL is using `{{ ds }}` while this is using `today.date()`. Is there anything else I cna do here?

Comment: I see, didn't understand from the question which code you meant - added a note

Comment: It can be solved but to help you must post your code

Answer (score 0):

I saw you were using custom operators

When inherit from BaseOperator, add `template_fields = ["my_date"]` in your class. Argument `my_date` will be disposed as Jinja templates. Otherwise it is just a normal string.

See details

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#templating